# Why my query return null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to ask why query return null and not update what i want. Sorry I'm still new with `asp.net` and `c#`

```
myquery = "UPDATE kenderaan SET buatan = " + "'" + carmake + "'" + "," +
          "model = " + "'" + carmodel + "'" + "," +
          "no_enjin = " + "'" + carenjin + "'" + "," +
          "cc = " + carcc + "," +
          "seatCapacity = " + carseat + "," +
          "tahunBuatan = " + caryear + " WHERE no_kenderaan = " + "'" + carid + "'" + "," +
          "AND ic = " + "'" + cusid + "'";


connection = new DbConnection();
connection.Update(myquery);
```

Answer (score 3):

restructure your code into this, use `Connection` object, `Command` Object, `using` statement.

```
string myquery = "UPDATE kenderaan SET buatan = @carmake ," +
              "     model = @carmodel ," +
              "     no_enjin =  @carenjin ," +
              "     cc = @carcc ," +
              "     seatCapacity =  @carseat ," +
              "     tahunBuatan = @caryear " +
              "WHERE no_kenderaan = @carid " +
              "     AND ic = @cusid ";

using (MySqlConnection _conn = new MySqlConnection("connectionStringHere"))
{
    using (MySqlCommand _comm = new  MySqlCommand())
    {
        _comm.Connection = _conn;
        _comm.CommandText = myquery;
        _comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmake",carmake);
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmodel",carmodel);
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carenjin",carenjin);
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carcc",carcc);
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carseat",carseat);
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caryear",caryear);
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid",carid);
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusid",cusid);

        try
        {
            _conn.Open();
            _comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); // as mentioned on the comment
        }

    }
}
```

Reasons why you need to parameterized your query:

- avoids SQL Injection
- makes your code more readable
- etc.. :D

Sources

- [**AddWithValue**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)
- [**Add** (**recommended** and *leaving you this as an assignment* :D)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x.aspx)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I almost did. e.Message.ToString() is a bad habit. Use e.ToString() instead to show inner exceptions and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DbCommand` to execute the `Update` statement by using `ExecuteNonQuery()` method. If you are using `SQL Server` then you can use this piece of code snippet:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string query = "UPDATE kenderaan SET buatan = @carmake" +
          ", model = @carmodel" +
          ", no_enjin =  @carenjin" +
          ", cc = @carcc" +
          ", seatCapacity = @carseat" +
          ", tahunBuatan = @caryear" +
          " WHERE no_kenderaan = @carid AND ic = @cusid";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmake", carmake);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carmodel", carmodel);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carenjin", carenjin);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carcc", carcc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carseat", carseat);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caryear", caryear);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", carid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusid", cusid);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the try/catch, or else readers will think that an empty `catch` block is the way to handle exceptions.

Comment: I have changed it as per your instructions. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in place of your code:

and make sure that varchar parameters are compare to string values.

```
 string myquery = "UPDATE kenderaan SET buatan = '" + carmake + "',model = '"+ 
 carmodel + "',no_enjin = '" +carenjin + "',cc = " + carcc + ",seatCapacity = " + 
 carseat + ",tahunBuatan = " + caryear +
 " WHERE no_kenderaan = '" + carid +  "' AND ic = '" + cusid + "'";


        connection = new DbConnection();
        connection.Update(myquery);
```

**UPDATED:** Apologize, I had just corrected your query with your where condition I just removed comma which you used to separate two condition.

To avoid SQL Injection Attacks, Use one of these :

1) `Parameters with Stored Procedures`

2) `Use Parameters with Dynamic SQL`

3) `Constrain Input`

you can find more information over [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: But still no mention of SQL Injection attacks, or how to avoid them.

Comment: I have just corrected the error of question. But for avoiding SQL Injections this is totally wrong manner to execute SQL Query. I suggest to use Stored Procedure with every different parameters declared for different values which you want to pass into back end side.

Comment: Note that http://stackoverflow.com/a/13244189/76337 answers the question and also solves the SQL injection problem.